# Given area of circle, find the radius of each circle that can fit the area

Tags: algorithms, circles

I have the following given values:

- area of the big circle
- values ranging from 1 to 100 (it can be more or less)

I need to create a circle for each value, where its size is proportional to its value.  For example, a value of 5 will become a circle that is smaller, while a value of 20 will become a larger circle.

Then, all these circles should fit inside the big circle.

My goal is to find the radius of each circle.

Comment: Not clear to me, but if the values are $A_1,A_2,A_3,\ldots$, and each one is to be interpreted as the area $A_i = \pi r_i^2$ of the $i$-th circle, then $$r_i = \sqrt{\frac{A_i}{\pi}}$$ Is that helpful? ___EDIT:___ Or is this instead a packing problem where you try to pack a bunch of circular discs of different sizes into one big circle? In that case, it is hard to find an optimal packing!

Comment: I think it's straightforward to get the radius of each circle whose area is Ai.  However, I still need to know the area of each circle, which is the Ai of each circle.  This is provided that all these circles will be packed inside a big circle having an area of, say, Abig.  Meaning Abig > A1 + A2 +.... An.

Comment: @iPhoneJavaDev What are you doing this for? Do you need a visualization for $100 = 50 + 25 + 10 + 7 + 5 + 3$ that involves pouring little circles into a big one in a way that visually fills up the big circle? Like Jeppe mentioned, this is a fairly intensive problem and I might suggest not using circles. Maybe stuff flexible bubbles in there? ...

Comment: Yes, I need to display the data into bubble chart.  However, I need them to be circles that merge in the center forming a big circle.  The reason that Abig > A1 + A2 + ... An is that if I pack those circles together, there will be gaps among them to avoid overlapping of circles.  I try to scale the radius of each circle based on their value, however, for some case, they perfectly fit the big area Abig.  For some combinations of data, they overflow.  And for some case, they form into a circle much smaller than Abig.  I need to scale the circles based on their value to somehow fit Abig properly.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have 4 circles of radius $r$ each at the corner of a square having side length =$2r$.

Then the area of this square is $4r^2$. One quarter of each of these 4 circles lies inside the square totaling an area of an entire circle, $\pi r^2$. So for a given square, circles packed in this way  will only cover $\frac{\pi}{4}$ of the area.

Repeat this with a regular triangle and we find the corresponding ratio to be $\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}$

Each of these processes corresponds to a way of packing circles into an area. However you pack the circles, some gaps will be present and with a signature ratio.

So given a square of side length $L$, how many circles of radius $r$ can fit?

The area of the square that can be occupied by Square Corner packing is $\frac{\pi}{4}L^2$

Divide this by the area of the circle to get $N=\frac{L^2}{4r^2}$. So N circles will fit.

The same principle applies for circles. Suppose you have a big circle with radius $r_1$ and you want to fill it with circles of radius $r_2$.

Then $$N=\frac{(\frac{\pi}{4})\pi r_1^2}{\pi r_2^2}=\frac{\pi r_1^2}{4r_2^2}$$

There are different ways of packing, and radii can be non-uniform, but once you know the packing fractions, you can usually sort things out.